# Creation of a new table in Power Bi Desktop

Tags: powerbi

I have a problem with Power Bi.

In fact, I have 2 tables A (before) and B (after) which represent changes in activities, as well as its schedules for customers.
The same customer has several different business lines. Sometimes there are changes at the activity, but sometimes the activity is not changed at all, but location change in table B (after). They are connected to each other with the unique key

I would like to obtain the final table C, which will only have one line per customer, and which would allow me to see:

- the difference in minutes from the start of the day (after - before)
- the difference in minutes for the end of the day (after - before)
- the total number of "work" in the "activities' type" column
- total number of jobs modified
- if the working hour has been modified
- if the job number has been modified

Thank you

[image: Table A]

[image: Table B]

[image: Table C]

Comment: From what you described a join will do the trick. But to make it work you need to find something to be your Primary Key. The column Key looks like a good candidate if you manage to do some treatment before joining the tables.

Comment: Hi, I have already joined my tables A and B with the primary key, but my problem is that I can't create a new column or a new measure in a new table C

Comment: I tried to create a new column with "IF" in table C, but it didn't work, since the columns I need are not present in table C.
Then, I also tried to create new measures with "Calculate" or "RELATED", but that doesn't work either, especially when I try to add conditions

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is:

1. Create Table C containing only **column Key**.
2. Create a relationship between A and C, B and C using **column Key**.
3. Create a new calculated column in Table C, taking A and B data.

IMPORTANT: in step 3) the calculation has to be done using the function CALCULATE in order to explicit the relation A,C and B,C

```
Result = CALCULATE(SUM(data from Table A),Table C[Key]=Table A[Key]) 
       + CALCULATE(SUM(data from Table B),Table C[Key]=Table B[Key])
```